# C++ initialization list of derived class failed to compile, why?

Tags: c++, list, class, constructor, derived

I've got a simple program to test initialization list, as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Base{
    Base():m_i(2){}
    int m_i;
};
struct Derived:Base{
    Derived():m_i(3){}
};
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, it fails to compile. Both gcc and clang gives and error:

```
1.cpp:7:15: error: member initializer 'm_i' does not name a non-static data member or base class
    Derived():m_i(3){}
          ^~~~~~
```

Where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect the value of `m_i` to be? 3 or 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `m_i` can be used in the `Derived` structure, it's not actually a *member* of the `Derived` structure, and can therefore not be used in a constructor initializer list.

The constructor initializer list can only initialize the *direct* class or structure members, not members from base classes. Or "call" the base class constructor.

You should add a `Base` constructor taking the value of `m_i` as an argument, and use that constructor in the `Derived` initializer list:

```
Derived() : Base(3) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message from the compiler is clear enough.

`m_i` is neither a non-static data member of the class nor is it a base class. Hence, it can't be used in

```
Derived():m_i(3){}
```

If you want to set the value of `m_i` to `3`, you can use the body of the constructor to do that.

```
Derived() { m_i = 3; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize members of one class from another class, including derived classes of the first class. There's a few different ways that you can do what you want. One is to use a constructor and pass the value of i as a parameter to it, like this:

```
struct Base{
    Base(int i=2):m_i(i){}
    int m_i;
};
struct Derived:Base{
    Derived():Base(3){}
};
```

Another is to just assign the variable instead of initializing it, like this:

```
struct Derived:Base{
    Derived(){
        m_i=3;
    }
};
```